# Adding More Empirics During "Revise and Resubmit" Process?

Tags: peer-review, journals

So, I (an early career researcher) have an article submitted to a journal in Political Science. In the article, I use several interviews with very specific and very busy people from my related field. However, after I submitted the article, one participant-to-be got back in touch and said they have time now and we can conduct the interview. I did that. That participant gave some nice quotes and basically confirmed my research outcomes alongside others. Now, the amount of interviews in the paper is on the lower side of the spectrum and I want to include the last one as well.

The question is: Is it weird if I add another interview in the revision process to the paper? So, for example, it will go from six to seven interviews. I will, of course, explain what happened in the response letter as well (late response; it was in line with what the other interviewees offered; if there were something abruptly wrong, I would have pulled the paper anyway).

So is it acceptable to add more supporting empirical data at this point? Again, analysis does not change, premise does not change, etc.

Answer (score 5):

If it improves the paper, especially its reliability, then I see no reason not to add the new material. As you suggest, giving the editor a heads up is correct, though it might slow down acceptance if they think a more complete review is needed.

If the new material is consistent with the old, it might not be needed, but on the other hand, the editor might just accept it without much worry.

If they don't like what you have done then you can go back to the original, but that doesn't seem especially likely.

Comment: So, I'll just add this to the response letter for each reviewer and the editor, at the very beginning. The revisions they asked were straightforward but editor called it "major revisions" - though I got the point, the changes are minor but they are major for it to be publishable. But should I send an email to the editor beforehand or revision letter is enough?

Comment: It is probably enough to point out the changes when you submit the revision.